# jQuery search using .find of content inside tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to search through the p tag content inside the .list and I'm probably just over complicating this but my alert isn't working, maybe it's because of other code I have on the page this isn't functioning but I was wondering if someone can help me figure out where I'm going wrong.

JS

```
            $(document).ready(function() {
            var sresults = $('.mainsearch input').val();

            var sfinder = $('.list p').find(sresults).text(sresults);


            $('.mainsearch input').keyup(function () {
             $('.search-help').append(sfinder);

             alert(sfinder);

            });
            });
```

HTML

```
            <div class="mainsearch">
            <input/>
            <div class="search-help">Results:
            </div>
            </div>


            <div class="list">
            <span><p>test</p></span>
            <span><p>another result</p></span>
            <span><p>yet another result</p></span>
            </div>
```

Comment: What does "my alert is not working" mean? What would you like it to do, and what is it doing? Your code should be alerting something (probably an empty dialog, on the account of `sfiner` not being defined anywhere) every time you lift a finger from a key from your `input` field.

Comment: sresults is not going to contain anything since your `input` tag has no attributes to it, so the find has nothing to find

Comment: What is `sfinder` supposed to contain? The code you're using to assign a value to that variable makes no sense.

Comment: @Blazemonger: Whatever `sfinder` contains of not, `sfiner` is undefined. There's too much wrong here to decipher the intention. People should learn to actually ask questions, and not just splurge code onto a page. OP, you'd do well to write the input and expected output next time.

Comment: Hey guys sorry for the typo it's supposed to be alert(sfinder);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('.mainsearch input').keyup(function () {
     var sresults = $('.mainsearch input').val();
     var sfinder = $('p:contains('+sresults+')').text();
     $('.search-help').text("Results:" + sfinder);
         alert(sfinder);
     });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h7uYB/

## Update:

try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/h7uYB/2/

Comment: Is there a way to add a break after this..

var sfinder = $('p:contains('+sresults+')').text(); +'<br/>'

Comment: @Blynn i was updating the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Typo?

`alert(sfiner)`

should be

`alert(sfinder)`

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [:contains() Selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/). From the website:

> Description: Select all elements that contain the specified text.
>   The matching text can appear directly within the selected element, in any of that element's descendants, or a combination thereof. As with attribute value selectors, text inside the parentheses of :contains() can be written as a bare word or surrounded by quotation marks. The text must have matching case to be selected.

So for you:

```
var sfinder = $('.list p:contains(' + sresults + ')');
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you just trying to return the paragraphs that match what's typed? Then you want to use [`:contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.mainsearch input').keyup(function() {
        var sresults = $('.mainsearch input').val();
        var sfinder = $('.list p:contains("' + sresults + '")');
        //$('.search-help').append(sfinder);

        console.log(sfinder);

    });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/kQnTV/

You might be aiming for this, though:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.mainsearch input').keyup(function() {
        var sresults = $('.mainsearch input').val();
        var sfinder = $('.list p:contains("' + sresults + '")');
        $('.search-help').html(sfinder.clone());
    });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/kQnTV/1/